# Percentage formula showing extra numbers

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column-formula, formula

I'm trying to get a SharePoint formula to show a percentage of time remaining on a contract. I'm nearly there but it's showing a lot of numbers to the right of the decimal point. I've tried a few things, rounding up, min, max but nothing seems to get rid of those pesky numbers. Any ideas? I'm using SP Online and this is my formula:

```
 =MAX(0,TodayDate-[Contract Commencement Date])/([Contract End Date]-[Contract Commencement Date])
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use **Round** function to rounds a number to a specified number of digits.

```
Round Syntax = ROUND(number,num_digits)
```

Where the `num_digits` the number of digits to which you want to round the number.

**In your case, try the following:**

```
=ROUND(MAX(0,TodayDate-[Contract Commencement Date])/([Contract End Date]-[Contract Commencement Date]), 1)
```

Read details at [ROUND function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/round-function-b5e7cff8-5e61-4172-82f6-86308e403748)

Comment: Boom! Thanks that worked like a dream

Answer (score 3):

You could set the calculated column as below：

[image]